# custom REST Api - access denied - programmatically solution

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, rest-api

I'm trying to create an extension with a custom REST Api and I created the api2.xml and the model that will retrive my data. The only problem is that in order to access my endpoint I need to go to the admin dashboard and give permissions to access the resources for the guest role otherwise I will recieve an ***Access denied*** message when accessing it.

The thing is I'm looking for a programmatically solution, where the user doesn't need to go to the dashboard and do this configurations, does anyone have some idea about this?
Thank you.